# What is the best way to segregate other api request and mobile application api request?

Tags: android, react-native, api, mobile, graphql

I am using laravel with lighthouse graphql for backend. It serves api for both web application and mobile application with same graphql api. I have a request which have to segregate api request whether it is from mobile-application or other.

I tried using `user-agent` for which request from web-application/browser gives detail information but that from mobile-application doesnot gives detail information in user-agent, it just give `Okhttp/7.8.1`, which made harder to detect the request.

Passing a custom header might be the option, but it might get easily forged right?

So, what might be the best approach for this?

Comment: Anything from the client can be forged. As @Prabin suggests the simplest solution is a custom header. A more complicated solution is to host the same graphql api on two different urls, ex: myapp.com/graphql and m.myapp.com/graphql

Answer (score 1):

you can send the platform name(web/app) in the header of the request API and identify it.